# Create a higher delay in nth-child()?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to do a small checklist. This checklist should popup in a row. So that the first point comes first, then the second and so on.

So I tried it with this (the important point is the :nth-child() in CSS):

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.animated:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s
}
.animated:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s
}
.animated:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
.checklist_table {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.checklist_table tr {
  width: 100%;
}
.checklist_table td {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
.checklist_table td:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="checklist_table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="checkmark.png" width="50px" class="animated fadeInUp" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <p class="status_checklist_p">1</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="checkmark.png" class="animated fadeInUp" width="50px" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <p class="status_checklist_p">2</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="checkmark.png" class="animated fadeInUp" width="50px" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <p class="status_checklist_p">3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djMpr/23/)

Now the animation works. However not the delay.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I agree with @Paulie_D. This time I have edited the code into the question. You can always do the same by using the `<>` icon (insert code snippet) from the toolbar. Please don't work-around the quality check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation delay has no effect because those selectors don't select any element currently. Each `img` element with `class='animated'` is the first and only child of its parent `td` and this is why the selector selects nothing.

You should apply the selector based on the `tr` element's child index instead.

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
tr:nth-child(2) .animated {
  animation-delay: 1s
}
tr:nth-child(3) .animated {
  animation-delay: 2s
}
.animated:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
.checklist_table {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.checklist_table tr {
  width: 100%;
}
.checklist_table td {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
.checklist_table td:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="checklist_table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="checkmark.png" width="50px" class="animated fadeInUp" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <p class="status_checklist_p">1</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="checkmark.png" class="animated fadeInUp" width="50px" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <p class="status_checklist_p">2</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="checkmark.png" class="animated fadeInUp" width="50px" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <p class="status_checklist_p">3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```